# VBA Extremely Slow When Setting Dictionary Full of Objects to Nothing

Tags: excel, vba, performance, dictionary, collections

I've got a dictionary with string keys and filled with objects. Those objects contain a dictionary and that object contains three dictionaries. It's Three layers deep. I'm using Microsoft Scripting Runtime Dictionary Object.

Main Dictionary of string/object
 -Object Contains Dictionary(String,Object)
 --Dictionary of objects(string, object)
 --Dictionary of objects(string, object)
 --Dictionary of objects(string, object)

When I'm finished with the task and code is done, the dictionary is set to nothing. When that happens the Class_Terminate is called for each object in each of the dictionaries. This is extremely slow and I'm having trouble identifying the cause or a workaround.

I'm using the cTimer class to measure performance.

How can I increase performance of terminate or skip the terminate operation?  Is there some bug or work around with the dictionary object?

**BTW, this is excel 32bit.**

Is there an alternative way to structure the classes or different collection/array that would be faster eliminate this issue? Maybe a win32 call or something to work around this?

Sample code To Reproduce the Slowness Try changing i to 1000 or 10000:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFillAndDestroy()
    Dim c1 As Class1


    Dim myDict As Dictionary
    Set myDict = New Dictionary

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Set c1 = New Class1
        c1.Fill
        myDict.Add CStr(i), c1
    Next

    Set myDict = Nothing 'extremely slow!

End Sub
```

Class1

```
Option Explicit

Private mDictofClass2 As Dictionary


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mDictofClass2 = New Dictionary
    Fill
End Sub

Sub Fill()
    Dim c2 As Class2
    Set c2 = New Class2
    c2.Name = Format(mDictofClass2.Count, "0000000")
    Add c2
End Sub

Sub Add(aClass2 As Class2)
    mDictofClass2.Add aClass2.Name, aClass2
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mDictofClass2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Class 2

```
Option Explicit

Private mDictOfClass3 As Dictionary
Private mName As String

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mName
End Property

Property Let Name(inputName As String)
    mName = inputName
End Property

Private Sub Fill()
    Dim c3 As Class3
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        Set c3 = New Class3
        c3.Name = Format(i, "00")
        Add c3
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Add(aClass3 As Class3)
    mDictOfClass3.Add aClass3.Name, aClass3
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mDictOfClass3 = New Dictionary
    Fill
End Sub
```

Class 3

```
Option Explicit

Private mDictOfClass4 As Dictionary 'just a poco
Private mDictOfStrings As Dictionary
Private mDictOfDoubleArray As Dictionary
Private mName As String
Property Let Name(inputName As String)
    mName = inputName
End Property

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mName
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mDictOfDoubleArray = New Dictionary
    Set mDictOfClass4 = New Dictionary
    Set mDictOfStrings = New Dictionary
    Fill
End Sub

Private Sub Fill()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim numbers(3) As Double
    numbers(0) = 0.00514
    numbers(1) = 654
    numbers(2) = 45.2587414
    Dim c4 As Class4
    Dim key As String
    For i = 1 To 150
        key = Format(CStr(i), "000")
        mDictOfDoubleArray.Add key, numbers
        mDictOfStrings.Add key & "v ggbbbnbb", "cvggpoiubvtgb  b vgflkjklj  nnnn"
        Set c4 = New Class4
        c4.Name = key
        mDictOfClass4.Add c4.Name, c4
    Next


End Sub
```

Class 4

```
Option Explicit

Private d1 As Double
Private d2 As Double
Private d3 As Double
Private d4 As Double
Private d5 As Double
Private d6 As String
Private d7 As String
Private d8 As Double
Private d9 As Double
Private d10 As Double

Private t1 As String
Private t2 As String

Property Let Name(inputName As String)
    t1 = inputName
End Property

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = t1
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    d1 = 1
    d2 = 2
    d3 = 5
    d4 = 15
    d5 = 1254
    d6 = 13654
    d7 = 1586
    d8 = 1985.55
    d9 = 985
    d10 = 6.14598
    t2 = "asdfdasgft34 scvg"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do expect a helpful answer without showing the code [mcve]? An objects instance is terminated when there are no references to it anymore. If you terminate an object that contains many other objects, all objects may be terminates at same time. So performance of class terminate may be interresting.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I'm working on a reproducible example. My current code is propriety at the moment, so I will try to make something that mimics my scenario.

Comment: I guess the relevant question seems to be what's happening in the Terminate event?

Comment: So, initially terminate only closed a progress bar if it was not nothing. I know the rest of freeing the objects was automatic. I was wondering why a certain method too so long. So I stepped thru suspect portions. Nothing, until the end when I was done with the class and the calling method/sub exited. That class was no longer needed so terminate was called automatically...it froze. So, I set all dictionaries in the class to nothing in the terminate method. I stepped thru the terminate method and on one dictionary, low and behold, it eats up all the processor when setting it to nothing.

Comment: @GisMofx, and so how did you fix this?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Sample code added

Comment: @GisMofx Will try you example, after a short look each Class1 instance contains 20 * 150 = 3000 Class3 instances. So 1000 Class1 instances contain 3000000 dicts what may be too many to close at once properly.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thanks. My other thought is hitting a memory limit in 32bit excel at the same time.

Comment: @HTH do you have a similar problem?